# ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC MapRoute project to ASP.NET 3.0 endpoints MapAreaControllerRoute "This localhost page can't be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-routing

We are upgrading our application from ASP.NET Core 2.2 project to ASP.NET 3.0 that uses EndPoint routing. I am stuck on the following issue of "No webpage was found". I believe that I applied the correct changes to ASP.NET 3.0 and I have tried various changes.

**Here's the asp.net core 2.2 code areas**

startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        ......
            //Asp.net Core 2.2
            services.AddRouting();
            //AddMvc
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);


            .AddViewLocalization(
            LanguageViewLocationExpanderFormat.Suffix, options => { options.ResourcesPath = "Areas\\Resources"; })
            .AddDataAnnotationsLocalization();

       public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        .....
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                //
                routes.MapRoute(name: "Navigation", template: "Navigation/{controller}/{action}/{id?}";
```

We decorate our controllers with :

```
    namespace Areas.Navigation.Controllers
    {
        [Area("Navigation")]
        [Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")]

        public class NavigationHomeController : Controller
       {.......
```

Here's the **asp.net 3.0 code areas** that we have changed

startup.cs

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {

           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                //Endpoints Start
                endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(areaName: "Navigation", name: "Navigation", pattern: "Navigation/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

My **Razor Page** includes the following:

```
    <a asp-area="Navigation" asp-controller="NavigationHome" asp-action="IndexAsync">Navigation</a>
```

I get the following issue that I'm stuck on

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this was reviewing "Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0"   This was initially done, but a suggestion within this document was overlooked.

My project consists of 130 other Subprojects. To fix my problem I had do the following:

1. [Review "Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0" again.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
2. Remove all of the Core 2.2 references  to MapRoute in Startup. For example:

   ```
   routes.MapRoute(name: "Navigation", template:     
                   Navigation/{controller}/{action}/{id?}";
   ```
3. Use the suggestion from ["How to define an endpoint Route to multiple Areas"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58352836/how-to-define-an-endpoint-route-to-multiple-areas)
   In Startup the code looks like this:

   ```
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
       {
           endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
               name: "areas",
               areaName: "areas",
               pattern: "{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"
               );

           endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
           name: "default",
           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");});
   ```
4. And the final key item until we fix and update our code. **"Async suffix removal from controller action names"**

   ```
   services.AddMvc(options =>options.SuppressAsyncSuffixInActionNames = false);
   ```

   This was small detail that was missed in Startup as described in ["Migrate from ASP.NET Core 2.2 to 3.0"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)
5. After making the changes the Application is working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

By adorning your controller with `Route` attribure

```
[Area("Navigation")]
[Route("[area]/[controller]/[action]")] //<-- attribute routing
public class NavigationHomeController : Controller {
    //...
```

The controller is now using attribute routing and not convention based routing.

However, you did not enable attribute routing in configuration.

> In the following example:
>
> - `MapControllers` adds support for attribute-routed controllers.
> - `MapAreaControllerRoute` adds a conventional route for controllers in an area.
> - `MapControllerRoute` adds a conventional route for controllers.

```
//...

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    //Attribute routing
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    //Area convention-based routing
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
        areaName: "Navigation", 
        name: "Navigation", 
        pattern: "Navigation/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");

    //Convention-based routing
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

//...
```

This is done to avoid route conflicts when matching requests to registered routes.

When dealing with convention-based routing, the order of registration also plays a part on how the routing table interprets requests.

So make sure that specific routes are registered before more general routes. Areas should also be registered before general routes.

Comment: Your answer didn't fully solve our problem, but it helped guide us to our solution. I will grant you the bounty for this.